# ReactJS : Trying to print index of my array objects- which should change dynamically if i delete elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Im building whats basically a todo list app right now, for learning reactjs.

this is my initial state

```
 const  [listx,setlistx] =  useState( 

        [
        {id:0,flavor:'strawberry',qty:'5'},
        {id:1,flavor:'Vanilla', qty:'3'},
        {id:2, flavor:'butterscotch', qty:'2'}
        ]
          );
```

I basically want to render each element as a numbered list, but cant utilize the index for this. used map to pass data to a component .

```
            {                                
               listx.map(itemx =>(

                key={itemx.index}
                id={itemx.id}
```

It dosn't recognise key but prints id for the initial 3 elements, i could increment and add the id field for each element but it will remain static if i delete an element (right?)

one more thing i tried was calling a useEffect hook which did allow me to console.log the index of newly added element (which i strangely wasnt able to, otherwise) but i couldnt access any of the other methods from useEffect when i tried to update the state that way.

i also wrote a function with `arr.findIndex()` but it only returns index after i add the element, and i cant seem to access an element using

```
newID=findIndex(flavor,qty);
setlistx(listx[newID].id= newID;
```

i hope i made the problem clear enough

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't recognise `index` because you have no `index` in your objects

`{id:2, flavor:'butterscotch', qty:'2'}`

but you can use `id` for key if it will be unique

```
listx.map(itemx => (
   key={itemx.id}
   id={itemx.id}
)
```

if you want to delete an element I would use filter

`listx.filter(id => id !== idYouAreFilteringFor)`

then it will rerender the list without the deleted one

Comment: I Want the ID to be generated dynamically, pls see the explanation above.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you want to use index instead of id as it is static and facing issue with delete?

1. In array map function we have 2nd arg is for index

```js
listx.map((itemx, index) => (...))
```

But in react for key I would suggest not use index. For key i would suggest use id instead of index. Key is used in react for rendering performance purpose. For key you can use some unique id which will not keep changing. In your example id is not keep changing. If you will use index which will keep change if you delete item

Instead of static hard coded id i would suggest use uuid

2. And to delete element you can use filter method to delete element and set newly generated array to setlistx like below

say example you call handleDelete method on delete icon click then,

```js
const handleDelete = (id) => {
   setlistx( oldlistx => oldlistx.filter(item => item.id !== id));
}
```

Comment: What i want is, If my list is like 1-First item 2-Second Item 3- Third item after deleting the my 2nd item i.e (index1) then the third item will move to index1, and display as 1- First item 2-Third item

Comment: listx.map((itemx, index) => (...)) Will help to to get result as you expected. Once you delete item react component will be re-render and map function will call again that time index will change to index1 for third item. But still I am not understanding why you require to use index? Is because you want delete item based on index?

Comment: no i just want the ID property to update aftet each delete